# Debugging share extension on iphone not working

Tags: ios, iphone, share-extension

I'm trying to develop an application with a shared extension. I ran into an issue while attempting to debug my app on an iPhone. I receive an error message "could not attach to pid : unable to attach"; but on a simulator everything works fine.

I tried attaching to the process via Debug>Attack by PID or by Name, but nothing changed.
Am I doing something wrong? How should I proceed?

Thank you and regards, Milan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I found solution  in Project > TARGETS > Extensions > Build Settings> Architectures> Valid Architectures,

i did clicking on + 
and added arm64 architecture in Debbug and release option;